# Can't run yui jar file - missing variable name and missing } after function body

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, yui-compressor

I'm trying to run this command in the cmd:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar "C:\Users\Ehud\Desktop\test\dest\js\replacejs.js" -o       "C:\Users\Ehud\Desktop\test\dest\js.js" --charset utf-8 --verbose --preserve-semi
```

My OS is Win 7 64 bit, I have Java installed on my machine, and I'm running this command from the dir where the jar file is.
the strange thing is that this worked fine in a different machine, I can't get why I recive this errors:

[Error] 34:20missing variable name

[Error] 34:20missing } after function body

[Error] 34:20missing } after function body

Since I haven't seen in the net anything with } for runnig this, can I asume that something is simply wrong with the jar file?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those sound more like errors which yuicompressor has found in your .js file and it can't do its magic until the syntax errors are resolved.

For example: [missing } after function body... even though everything is closed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556863/missing-after-function-body-even-though-everything-is-closed-properly)

Go through your .js file with a fine-tooth comb (or a JavaScript editor which flags syntax errors) and see if you can find the problem in there.